# Extract Embedded Image Object in RTF

Tags: c#, .net, image, rtf

I have `rtf` documents that include an embedded object (an image). I need to extract this as an `Image` object (or any other usable format). I have checked out this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter) but the default apps don't render it correctly (They render the 'default image' image, not the image itself), so I moved on.

[image: This is a screen of the RTF in WordPad]

Here is a sample of the RTF Code (I had to shorten it because of size):

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1033\f0\fs18{\object\objemb{\*\objclass Package}\objw855\objh810{\*\objdata 
01050000
02000000
08000000
5061636b61676500
00000000
00000000
1f900000
02007369675f5f2e6a706700433a5c55736572735c726563657074696f6e5c4465736b746f705c
5369676e6174757265735c7369675f5f2e6a7067000000030034000000433a5c55736572735c52
45434550547e315c417070446174615c4c6f63616c5c54656d705c7369675f5f20283132292e6a
706700c18e0000ffd8ffe000104a46494600010101004800470000ffdb00430001010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101ffdb00430101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101ffc0001108012c03e803012200021101031101ffc4001f00010002030002
0301000000000000000000090a07080b050602030401ffc4003f10000006030001040201030301
04070900000203040506010708090a11121314152116172223314118192532591a24576598d6d8
2933384651788497b7ffc4001a010101000301010000000000000000000000030204050106ffc4
002b11010003010100020103030402030000000002030401051112130614211522230731415124
32536162ffda000c03010002110311003f00bfc000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
...
005c0072006500630065007000740069006f006e005c004400650073006b0074006f0070005c00
5300690067006e006100740075007200650073005c007300690067005f005f002e006a00700067
00
01050000
00000000
}{\result{\pict\wmetafile8\picw2010\pich1905\picwgoal855\pichgoal810 
0100090000033b0700000200210600000000050000000b0200000000050000000c02350038001c
000000fb02f4ff000000000000900100000001000000005365676f65205549000e0a52104c2308
00dd1900d894ef758001f3758d0e664a040000002d010000050000000902000000000500000001
02ffffff00a5000000410bc600880020002000000000002000200000000c002800000020000000
400000000100010000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffff
...
0021001c001c000000fb021000070000000000bc02000000000102022253797374656d00008d0e
664a00000a0022008a0100000000ffffffff8cdd1900040000002d010100030000000000
}}}\par
}
```

Comment: do you need to find a way to do this programmatically (that is, on numerous files), or do you just need a way to extract an image from a single document?

Comment: I need to do it programatically. I am retrieving the rtf code from a SQL database.

Comment: you do realize that the snippet you posted includes an OLE object followed by a picture. If you are trying to extract the former as a picture, I'm not surprised that it fails.

Comment: How would I go about extracting the `OLE` object then? It is a jpeg.

Comment: obligatory link to [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611459/how-to-convert-rtf-to-image-format-jpg-png), with caveat that the answers there have zero points.

Comment: That's not a duplicate... I am not trying to turn an rtf into an image. I am trying to extract the embedded object from an rtf and render it as an image.

Comment: I'm trying not to turn this into an extended discussion, but I advise you to do some more research and revise your question. The OLE object is not a jpeg -- it's not even a picture. The \pict element is a picture but it is not a JPEG -- its a WMF (note the tag "wmetafile8"). I think you need a better grasp on your input data.

Comment: I dragged and dropped a jpg into the rtf. I would assuem that the OLE object is the jpg (Wrapped in some sort of an OLE wrapper) and the `pict` is the icon that is embedded into the rtf. Opening the rtf in wordpad (seen in my image) and then double clicking the icon, opens my jpeg. ergo, I want to extract and decode the object and render the data as a jpeg. If the jpeg itself was the `pict` data, I would assume you would be seeing the image itself in the rtf, not the icon, and extracting it would be trivial.

Comment: Can you post the .rtf file somewhere so we can test?

Comment: It was too long for SO. Here is a download link: 2shared.com/document/QAf6JQqO/test.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that can extract all objects ('Package' class objects) from an RTF stream:

```
    public static void ExtractPackageObjects(string filePath)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            RtfReader reader = new RtfReader(sr);
            IEnumerator<RtfObject> enumerator = reader.Read().GetEnumerator();
            while(enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                if (enumerator.Current.Text == "object")
                {
                    if (RtfReader.MoveToNextControlWord(enumerator, "objclass"))
                    {
                        string className = RtfReader.GetNextText(enumerator);
                        if (className == "Package")
                        {
                            if (RtfReader.MoveToNextControlWord(enumerator, "objdata"))
                            {
                                byte[] data = RtfReader.GetNextTextAsByteArray(enumerator);
                                using (MemoryStream packageData = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    RtfReader.ExtractObjectData(new MemoryStream(data), packageData);
                                    packageData.Position = 0;
                                    PackagedObject po = PackagedObject.Extract(packageData);
                                    File.WriteAllBytes(po.DisplayName, po.Data);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here are the utility classes that this code uses. There is a simple stream-based RTF parser that allows to get to the interesting control words.

There is also a utility to extract data from a serialized Object Packager instance. Object Packager is an almost 20-years ago [OLE1.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding) thing and the serialized binary format is not documented (to my knowledge), but it's understandable.

This works fine on your provided sample, but you may have to adapt things around.

```
public class RtfReader
{
    public RtfReader(TextReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");

        Reader = reader;
    }

    public TextReader Reader { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<RtfObject> Read()
    {
        StringBuilder controlWord = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        Stack<RtfParseState> stack = new Stack<RtfParseState>();
        RtfParseState state = RtfParseState.Group;

        do
        {
            int i = Reader.Read();
            if (i < 0)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controlWord.ToString()))
                    yield return new RtfControlWord(controlWord.ToString());

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text.ToString()))
                    yield return new RtfText(text.ToString());

                yield break;
            }

            char c = (char)i;

            // noise chars
            if ((c == '\r') ||
                (c == '\n'))
                continue;

            switch (state)
            {
                case RtfParseState.Group:
                    if (c == '{')
                    {
                        stack.Push(state);
                        break;
                    }

                    if (c == '\\')
                    {
                        state = RtfParseState.ControlWord;
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                case RtfParseState.ControlWord:
                    if (c == '\\')
                    {
                        // another controlWord
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controlWord.ToString()))
                        {
                            yield return new RtfControlWord(controlWord.ToString());
                            controlWord.Clear();
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    if (c == '{')
                    {
                        // a new group
                        state = RtfParseState.Group;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controlWord.ToString()))
                        {
                            yield return new RtfControlWord(controlWord.ToString());
                            controlWord.Clear();
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    if (c == '}')
                    {
                        // close group
                        state = stack.Count > 0 ? stack.Pop() : RtfParseState.Group;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controlWord.ToString()))
                        {
                            yield return new RtfControlWord(controlWord.ToString());
                            controlWord.Clear();
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
                    {
                        state = RtfParseState.Text;
                        text.Append(c);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controlWord.ToString()))
                        {
                            yield return new RtfControlWord(controlWord.ToString());
                            controlWord.Clear();
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    controlWord.Append(c);
                    break;

                case RtfParseState.Text:
                    if (c == '\\')
                    {
                        state = RtfParseState.EscapedText;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (c == '{')
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text.ToString()))
                        {
                            yield return new RtfText(text.ToString());
                            text.Clear();
                        }

                        // a new group
                        state = RtfParseState.Group;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (c == '}')
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text.ToString()))
                        {
                            yield return new RtfText(text.ToString());
                            text.Clear();
                        }

                        // close group
                        state = stack.Count > 0 ? stack.Pop() : RtfParseState.Group;
                        break;
                    }
                    text.Append(c);
                    break;

                case RtfParseState.EscapedText:
                    if ((c == '\\') || (c == '}') || (c == '{'))
                    {
                        state = RtfParseState.Text;
                        text.Append(c);
                        break;
                    }

                    // ansi character escape
                    if (c == '\'')
                    {
                        text.Append(FromHexa((char)Reader.Read(), (char)Reader.Read()));
                        break;
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text.ToString()))
                    {
                        yield return new RtfText(text.ToString());
                        text.Clear();
                    }

                    // in fact, it's a normal controlWord
                    controlWord.Append(c);
                    state = RtfParseState.ControlWord;
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (true);
    }

    public static bool MoveToNextControlWord(IEnumerator<RtfObject> enumerator, string word)
    {
        if (enumerator == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerator");

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (enumerator.Current.Text == word)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static string GetNextText(IEnumerator<RtfObject> enumerator)
    {
        if (enumerator == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerator");

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            RtfText text = enumerator.Current as RtfText;
            if (text != null)
                return text.Text;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static byte[] GetNextTextAsByteArray(IEnumerator<RtfObject> enumerator)
    {
        if (enumerator == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerator");

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            RtfText text = enumerator.Current as RtfText;
            if (text != null)
            {
                List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
                for (int i = 0; i < text.Text.Length; i += 2)
                {
                    bytes.Add((byte)FromHexa(text.Text[i], text.Text[i + 1]));
                }
                return bytes.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Extracts an EmbeddedObject/ObjectHeader from a stream
    // see [MS -OLEDS]: Object Linking and Embedding (OLE) Data Structures for more information
    // chapter 2.2: OLE1.0 Format Structures 
    public static void ExtractObjectData(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream)
    {
        if (inputStream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("inputStream");

        if (outputStream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("outputStream");

        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(inputStream);
        reader.ReadInt32(); // OLEVersion
        int formatId = reader.ReadInt32(); // FormatID
        if (formatId != 2) // see 2.2.4 Object Header. 2 means EmbeddedObject
            throw new NotSupportedException();

        ReadLengthPrefixedAnsiString(reader); // className
        ReadLengthPrefixedAnsiString(reader); // topicName
        ReadLengthPrefixedAnsiString(reader); // itemName

        int nativeDataSize = reader.ReadInt32();
        byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes(nativeDataSize);
        outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    // see chapter 2.1.4 LengthPrefixedAnsiString
    private static string ReadLengthPrefixedAnsiString(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        int length = reader.ReadInt32();
        if (length == 0)
            return string.Empty;

        byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes(length);
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes, 0, length - 1);
    }

    private enum RtfParseState
    {
        ControlWord,
        Text,
        EscapedText,
        Group
    }

    private static char FromHexa(char hi, char lo)
    {
        return (char)byte.Parse(hi.ToString() + lo, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    }
}

// Utility class to parse an OLE1.0 OLEOBJECT
public class PackagedObject
{
    private PackagedObject()
    {
    }

    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }
    public string IconFilePath { get; private set; }
    public int IconIndex { get; private set; }
    public string FilePath { get; private set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; private set; }

    private static string ReadAnsiString(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        do
        {
            byte b = reader.ReadByte();
            if (b == 0)
                return sb.ToString();

            sb.Append((char)b);
        }
        while (true);
    }

    public static PackagedObject Extract(Stream inputStream)
    {
        if (inputStream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("inputStream");

        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(inputStream);
        reader.ReadUInt16(); // sig
        PackagedObject po = new PackagedObject();
        po.DisplayName = ReadAnsiString(reader);
        po.IconFilePath = ReadAnsiString(reader);
        po.IconIndex = reader.ReadUInt16();
        int type = reader.ReadUInt16();
        if (type != 3) // 3 is file, 1 is link
            throw new NotSupportedException();

        reader.ReadInt32(); // nextsize
        po.FilePath = ReadAnsiString(reader);
        int dataSize = reader.ReadInt32();
        po.Data = reader.ReadBytes(dataSize);
        // note after that, there may be unicode + long path info
        return po;
    }
}

public class RtfObject
{
    public RtfObject(string text)
    {
        if (text == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("text");

        Text = text.Trim();
    }

    public string Text { get; private set; }
}

public class RtfText : RtfObject
{
    public RtfText(string text)
        : base(text)
    {
    }
}

public class RtfControlWord : RtfObject
{
    public RtfControlWord(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, could you tell please where have you read information about OLE structure for public static PackagedObject Extract(Stream inputStream) function? I can't find anything about fields sig, DisplayName, IconFilePath in docs. @SimonMourier

Comment: did you ever stumble upon (and solve) the problem that some file types like .docx or .xlsx are not fully supported (they can be opened but not extracted with the code above)?

Comment: @Breeze - docx and xlsx are not rtf-based documents. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean docx or xlsx files that are embedded as objects inside the rtf

Comment: I have the same issue now ! please help me now. Link : **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52927298/reading-rtf-file-containing-an-ole-embedded-object** @SimonMourier

Answer (score 5):

OK, this should work for you. To demonstrate my solution, I created a WinForms project with a PictureBox whose paint event handler was mapped to the following function:

```
 private void rtfImage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        string rtfStr = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("MySampleFile.rtf");
        string imageDataHex = ExtractImgHex(rtfStr);
        byte[] imageBuffer = ToBinary(imageDataHex);
        Image image;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBuffer))
        {
            image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, rect);                        
    }
```

This code relies the on the [System.Drawing.Image.FromStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream.aspx) method, along with two "helper" functions:

### A string extractor:

```
    string ExtractImgHex(string s)
    {
        // I'm sure you could use regex here, but this works.
        // This assumes one picture per file; loops required otherwise
        int pictTagIdx = s.IndexOf("{\\pict\\");
        int startIndex = s.IndexOf(" ", pictTagIdx)+1;
        int endIndex = s.IndexOf("}", startIndex);
        return s.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
    }
```

### ... and a binary converter:

```
    public static byte[] ToBinary(string imageDataHex)
    {
        //this function taken entirely from:
        // http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter
        if (imageDataHex == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("imageDataHex");
        }

        int hexDigits = imageDataHex.Length;
        int dataSize = hexDigits / 2;
        byte[] imageDataBinary = new byte[dataSize];

        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(2);

        int dataPos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < hexDigits; i++)
        {
            char c = imageDataHex[i];
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            {
                continue;
            }
            hex.Append(imageDataHex[i]);
            if (hex.Length == 2)
            {
                imageDataBinary[dataPos] = byte.Parse(hex.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                dataPos++;
                hex.Remove(0, 2);
            }
        }
        return imageDataBinary;
    }
```

Comment: This is very close. The `pict` data is the icon (seen in image1) that the jpeg is embedded. Double clicking that icon in an RTF reader opens the actual Image I want, which I assume is embedded in the `object` data. This is what this code gets me: http://i.imgur.com/TXy0Gv4.png

Comment: please clarify how the .rtf file was created. How exactly was the image originally embedded into the file? You said in an earlier comment that you just dragged & dropped a .jpeg into the rtf. But when I do that, only the `pict` tag is created. I would like to create a test file with the same tags as yours (unless you can make the full text of your sample file available somewhere).

Comment: In MS Word try Insert->Object->From File. That seems to do what I have. (I am using a Line of Business application to create them). An example of my file is here: http://www.2shared.com/document/QAf6JQqO/test.html

Comment: Well, unfortunately that is not nearly as easy. The JPEG data embedded in the `object` has been encoded (most likely with `[OleSaveToStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678407(v=vs.85).aspx)`, and extracting it is going to be painful. (In C#, that is. I understand that VB has a RichTextBox control that you could load your rtf into and then access all the OLEObjects in file. Unfortunately, the RichTextBox in C# doesn't provide that access.) I'm afraid I'm at a dead end. Sorry.

Comment: Alright, I will have to look into the `VB` thing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, sorry again, but my VB comment is out of date too, unfortunately. You're not going to find OLE support in .NET at all. OLE is an archaic technology; you'd need to interface with the Win32 API (using C++ or something).

Comment: @kmote I have an rtf file with embedded graphic 120x260.  After running your code above, after `image = Image.FromStream(stream);` the image is 1920x1080 (the size of my screen).  Is there a way to recreate the image the original size?

Comment: I was able to solve the size problem by reading the \picw and \pich values and resizing the image to that size. But, I'm still wondering if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Below code can extract all type of embedded objects. including image/docs/mails etc with original file name. And save them in a local path.

```js
string MyDir = @"E:\temp\";
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "Requirement#4.rtf");

NodeCollection nodeColl = doc.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Shape, true);
foreach (var node in nodeColl)
{
    Shape shape1 = (Shape)node;
    if (shape1.OleFormat != null)
    {
        shape1.OleFormat.Save(MyDir + shape1.OleFormat.SuggestedFileName + shape1.OleFormat.SuggestedExtension);
    }
}
```