# How to send image inside richtextbox in mail

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a image inside richtextbox in windows form. I want to send that image through mail . I converted the rtf to html , but then the image format is changed to wmf and it is not displaying.

Comment: how did you convert to html? most browsers won't show wmf, but if it converted to a GIF or PNG and inline, it should work.

Comment: i got the code for converting rtf to html  from stackoverflow.com/questions/5265566/simple-convert-rtf-to-html

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the objects (like images i.e) from an rtf. But thats not so easy. So take a look at [stackoverflow 14779647 extract-embedded-image-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779647/extract-embedded-image-object-in-rtf) for an example code. After extracted attach it to your mailmessage.

Comment: <p><b><span style="color:#76923C;background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Bookman Old Style;font-size:11pt;">Respected Sir/Madam</span></b></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><img width="58" height="42" src="1.wmf" /><span style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt;"> &lt;http://mfabtech.com/images/gallery/a2.jpg&gt; </span><img width="55" height="45" src="2.wmf" /><span style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt;"> </span><img width="60" height="44" src="3.wmf" />

Comment: image is coming in wmf  format. It is not showing in browser

Comment: do you need that HTML way?? i dont think so - use the approach from my referenced stackoverflow answer plz