# VB.NET out of memory exception

Tags: vb.net, out-of-memory, ram

This is my code to populate a flow-layout-panel with pictureboxes :

```
  For Each fi As FileInfo In New DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath + "\data\img\em_sml").GetFiles()
        Dim pbx1 As New PictureBox
        pbx1.Width = 32
        pbx1.Height = 32
        pbx1.BackColor = Color.Azure
        pbx1.Image = Image.FromFile(fi.FullName)
        AddHandler pbx1.Click, AddressOf pbx1_click
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pbx1)
    Next
```

Suddenly i am getting out-of-memory error in the following line :

```
    pbx1.Image = Image.FromFile(fi.FullName)
```

Why ? and how to fix it ?

**Don't know if this is relevant or not, but the problem never occurred when i was using 4 gb ram, yesterday i removed a 2 gb ram stick from my pc, now my pc runs on 2 gb ram. Till yesterday, this error was not there, but now this error appers. Does it have anything to do with RAM ?**

Comment: `Does it have anything to do with RAM ?` - Yes, you're loading multiple images that I'd say are probably bigger than 32 x 32, so eventually you'll run out of free RAM (images eat relatively much memory). Use an [**`ImageList`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. It automatically creates resized versions of the images you add to it, thus all images will have the same dimensions and take less memory than their original counterparts.

Comment: no...i already thought of what u suggested..But all my pics have the dimension of 20x20...so what now ? do i still need to use an imagelist ?

Comment: No, use more RAM or less images ;). See if you can make a more dynamic solution, loading them in batches.

Comment: @VisualVincent,what do u mean by use less image ? i can't even add 1 single image in a rich text box, same error occurs

Comment: I meant do not add so many images at one time, add them in batches if possible. Bare in mind that a Rich Text document usually take up way much more memory than what is actually needed.