# The simplest way to extract obj data in RTF file

Tags: java, asp.net-core, rtf, apache-tika

I want to extract the embedded OLE objects in the RTF file.
I prefer to implement it in Java, so I have read the doc & source code of Apache Tika RTFParser (1.25 & 2.0-ALPHA) and found that Tika just extracts text for search purpose and can't get the obj data. Perhaps it is feasible to write some code based on TextExtractor.

Then I also tried [this post in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14893493/4630864) but error on `if (type != 3) // 3 is file, 1 is link` in PackagedObject.Extract.

Can anyone help me to figure out what is the simplest way (less code) to extract obj data in the RTF file? Cross-platform and server-side solution is preferred (Java or .net-core). But using Word. Application in C# is not considerable, because it depends on the Word client and sometimes unexpectedly terminated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract the raw bytes with Apache Tika, try the -z commandline option with Tika app or the [/unpack endpoint](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaServer#TikaServer-UnpackResource) with tika-server.  Yes, Tika focuses on text/metadata extraction, but it can be used to extract raw embedded files as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this a useful starting point: https://github.com/joniles/mpxj/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sf/mpxj/mpp/RTFEmbeddedObject.java#L149

This was intended for users of MPXJ to extract objects embedded in RTF notes.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I tried the above code, but error length==-1 at `m_data = getData(blocks, length);` in RTFEmbeddedObject.RTFEmbeddedObject.

I realized that, the core of this question is to parse the embedded object according to its format spec, am I right?

Is there any way to know the byte length of the embedded object?